# Liferay application adapter does not work with javascript files

Tags: javascript, liferay, hook

I need to use application adapter to implement different functionality for different sites. If I set 'false' in liferay-hook.xml, and select appropriate adapter in liferay 'site settings' all modifications which are in **jsp files** are displayed but modifications in **js** files are not.

Any ideas how to use application adapter to customize js files per site?

Thanks a lot for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. An application adapter changes the way the application server resolves JSPs - while JS files are directly requested from the browser.

As JS files are typically minified, with no notion of different files due to the site, you'll have to make your JS files aware of the different conditions in which they run - e.g. introduce conditional initialization in them or embed different JS files in your themes (or make the themes configurable to include different JS files)